# http and ajax request simulation

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, http

I have the following url

```
 http://mywebsite/mypages
```

when you go to this url it will display a list of links, for example

```
 http://mywebsite/pages?page=1
 http://mywebsite/pages?page=2
 ...
```

when the user click on one of these links, an ajax request will be executed to bring the content of this page and then display the content in the same page (by same page i mean     mywebsite/mypages).

The question is: how can i simulate this behavior?. for example a user has a link:

```
 http://mywebsite/simulation?page=http://mywebsite/pages?page=1
```

when a user click this url, i want to redirect him/her to mywebsite/mypages and simulate a click on the link

```
 http://mywebsite/pages?page=1
```

so the user can see the content of this page.

Comment: Catch all anchor link clicks on the page and load the appropriate target html via Ajax. You can update the address bar (without changing page) with History.js

Comment: Would this help?

$script_url = "http".(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?"s":"")."://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$new_url = substr($script_url,strpos($script_url,"?page=")+6);
if (strpos($new_url,"mywebsite") != false) {
header('Location: '.$new_url);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First [read the url from the url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter) and store it in a server side control (e.g. a hidden field).
Then redirect to `http://mywebsite/mypages`, read your hidden fields value and perform your ajax request with it.
Alternatively you could store it somewhere else server side, e.g. a database.